# How to sort json files by keys

Tags: python, json

I have a json file, for example,

```
{
"2":{"name": "A", "Label": "Student"}, 
"3":{"name": "B", "Label": "Student"}, 
"1":{"name": "B", "Label": "Student"}, 
...
}
```

I want to sort the file by keys, then the result should be:

```
"1":{"name": "B", "Label": "Student"}, 
"2":{"name": "A", "Label": "Student"}, 
"3":{"name": "B", "Label": "Student"}, 
...
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Read it into an ordereddict?

Comment: What is the usecase of this? Objects in JSON are [unordered](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt) so whatever program or library will handle it should not rely on the order of the keys.

If you need order, you can use array.

Comment: For my use case, I want to reorder an appsettings file to make the settings easier to find and maintain. While my application doesn't care, it'll help out other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {
"2":{"name": "A", "Label": "Student"},
"3":{"name": "B", "Label": "Student"},
"1":{"name": "B", "Label": "Student"},
}

import json
from collections import OrderedDict

print(json.dumps(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items())), indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "B",
        "Label": "Student"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "A",
        "Label": "Student"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "B",
        "Label": "Student"
    }
}
```

EDIT: If your keys are integers encoded as string and you want to sort them ascending:

```
print(json.dumps(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k: int(k[0]))), indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply! what is the indent?

Comment: @SiruiLi The indent is here only for pretty printing, shorthand for indentation. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.dumps

Answer (score 4):

Try this, if you want it as JSON

```
import json    
json.loads(json.dumps(values, sort_keys=True))
```

Output

```
{"1": {"Label": "Student", "name": "B"}, "2": {"Label": "Student", "name": "A"}, "3": {"Label": "Student", "name": "B"}}
```

Comment: While simple, this solution sorts the keys as strings and therefore would put "20" before "3". ("2" < "3")